# how to encrypt a hash value using SHA512

Tags: ruby, hash, sha512

I'm trying to encrypt a hash using SHA512. but i'm getting can't convert hash into string. Any help is appreciated.

```
hash=Hash.new 
hash={first_name:"hari", last_name:"prakash", mobile:"12345" }
enc_hash= Digest::SHA2.new(512).digest(hash)
```

when i do this i'm getting

> TypeError: can't convert Hash into String

Please guide me. any study resource on this topic is appreciated.

Comment: SHA512, in fact any cryptographic hash function is **not** encryption. Encryption implies reversibility and the use of a key to accomplish that. Further, using the word "hash" for a dictionary is an artifact of Perl and now Ruby that just causes confusion.

Comment: Your question is massively unclear. First off, what does it mean to "encrypt a hash"? All known encryption algorithms work on streams of octets, streams of bits, streams of bytes, or streams of characters. There are no encryption algorithms that work on in-memory Ruby object graphs. And secondly, SHA512 is not an encryption algorithm, so you cannot encrypt anything with it, period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, digest works on strings. If you want encrypt it, you could convert it to string first:

```
Digest::SHA2.new(512).digest(hash.to_s)
```

Comment: that worked. but is there any other method to encrypt a hash without converting it into string.

Comment: @hari, not sure what encrypting a regular hash looks like in terms of implementation without stringifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this, hash only values inside hash?

```
hash.map { |k,v| hash[k] = Digest::SHA2.new(512).digest(v) }
```